# IIS URL Rewrite or Load Balancer for 301 Redirects?

Tags: iis, load-balancing, 301-redirect

We have a system in place with access to the IIS URL Rewrite Feature.
However, I am investigating whether we should do our 301 Redirects using it, on IIS, or do them at the Load Balancer stage instead?

I am leaning towards IIS as it may prove more flexible in future, but still I am just looking into this.

Could anyone offer any insight as to where, generally, 301 Redirects should be placed?

Thanks,
Dearg